# D3 single select and function invocation

Tags: javascript, function, select, d3.js, invoke

How can I call function after i successfully select using `d3.select()`?

At the moment I have this code:

```
var selectedCircle = d3.select("circle");
if(selectedCircle) {
    // do stuff
}
```

I want it to be something like that:

```
d3.select("circle")
    .function()( 
          // do stuff
    );
```

How can I do that?

P.S

---

I know that selectAll has similar functionality:

```
d3.selectAll("circle")
    .each(function() {
            // do stuff
    });
```

Comment: I don't really understand... if you follow common d3 patterns, you usually do a function after a select... for example: d3.select("circle").append("rect") . There are many examples out there... What is it exactly you want to do? select something and then do a custom function?

Comment: yes, let's say I want to get 2 attributes of that selected circle (center coordinates maybe), and then printout alert dialog with these two cx and cy values

Comment: Take a look on the each() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use call on selection

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#call

```
d3.select("circle").call(function(selection){
    // do stuff on selection
});
```